# Incomplete Data in my report

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've created a report and I use *rdlc* using Report Viewer but when I execute the project the data under column `student ID` and `Due Date` is missing.

```
Student ID |     Title    |   ISBN    | Date      |    Due Date|
             Volcano         971234     9/14/2013
              Algebra        974343     9/13/2013
```

The query is:

```
SELECT [Student ID], ISBN, Title, Date, [Due Date] FROM dbo.Borrowbook
```

Comment: We need to see your SQL query to even begin to venture a starting guess

Comment: SELECT [Student ID], ISBN, Title, Date, [Due Date] FROM dbo.Borrowbook

Comment: @christiandev the data under column student ID and due date is missing.

Comment: I thought this was just a statement, and the question was missing.  When you run the query in SSMS, you get the data back?

Comment: @christiandev I try to run it in SSMS and it runs properly and complete data

Comment: Have you got the report set up to bind to the fields being returned? something like `=!Fields.[Student ID]`

Comment: Where can I see that?